# Grub strings to .po files which has been passed to ugettext as variables

Tags: python, django, internationalization, gettext

I am using `Django==1.8.4`.

Within django application i am using ugettext to get translated message in next way:

```
id = 1
message = "Some message %(id)s" % {'id':id}
return JsonResponse({'message': ugettext(message)})
```

In django official documentation there are **note** regarding translating variables with ugettext.

> (The caveat with using variables or computed values, as in the
>   previous two examples, is that Django’s translation-string-detecting
>   utility, django-admin makemessages, won’t be able to find these
>   strings. More on makemessages later.

Source: [Django documentation page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/i18n/translation/#standard-translation)

Is there are any other way to grub messages to .po files automatically without refactoring all calling of `ugettext` ( pass direct string into ugettext instead of variable)  ?

Answer (score 1):

Call ugettext on the string literal before substituting variables.

```
message = ugettext("Some message %(id)s") % {'id':id}
```

Comment: Thanks, i know that's possible. The question is how to avoid such refactoring.

Comment: I don't think it is. The variable `message` will be different every time, so it would need to generate messages for each version in the .po file.

How do you want your .po file messages to look like?

BTW, you forgot the {} around the dict in the argument to JsonResponse; `JsonResponse({'message': ugettext(message)})`.

Comment: The **canonical** way is to annotate all translated source strings in source code, i.e. `message = _("Some message %(id)s") % {'id':id}` so that 3rd party tools can find all these strings, i.e. for static analysis. (Obv, `from xx import ugettext as _`) Note that this "refactoring" is just 3 characters for each user-facing string, `_()`. The alternative is to build your own toolchain... And then just try explaining it to some other developer who has to support your code later.